# Hadoop reduce become slower when there are less reduce task

Tags: dictionary, hadoop, configuration, reduce, shuffle

I'm experiencing a really weird case when I am doing some performance tuning of Hadoop. I was running a job with large intermediate output (like InvertedIndex or WordCount without combiner), the network and computation resources are all homogeneous. According to how mapreduce work, when there is more **WAVES** of reduce task, the overall run time should be slower as there is less overlap between map and shuffle, but it is not the case. It turns out that the job with 5 WAVES of reduce task is about 10% faster than the one with only one WAVE of task. And I checked the log and it turns out that the map tasks' execution time is longer when there is less reduce tasks, also, the overall computation time(not shuffle or merge) during reduce phase is longer when there is less task. I tried to rule out other factors by setting reduce slow-start factor to be 1 so that there is no overlap between map and shuffle, I also limited it to be only one reduce task to be executed at the same time so there is no overlap between reduce tasks, and I modified the scheduler to force mapper and reducer to locate on different machines so there is no I/O congestion. Even with above approach, the same thing still happen. (I also set the map memory buffer to be large enough and the io.sort.factor to be 32 or even larger and io.sort.mb to be larger than 320 accordingly)

I really can't think of any other reason that cause this problem, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**Just in case of confusion, the problem I am experiencing is:**

**0. I'm comparing the performance of running 1 reduce task vs 5 reduce task of the same job under all other same configurations. There is only one tasktracker for reduce computation.**

**1. I have forced all reduce task to be executed sequentially by having only one tasktracker for redcue task in both cases, and mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum=1, so there won't be any parallelism during reduce phase**

**2. I have set mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps=1 so none of the reducer will start to pull data before all map is done**

**3. It turns out that having one reduce task is slower than having 5 SEQUENTIAL reduce tasks!**

**4. Even if I set set mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps=0.05 to allow overlap between map & shuffle, (thus when there is only one reduce task, the overlap should be more and it should run faster, because the 5 reduce task are SEQUENTIALLY executing) the 5-reduce-task is still faster than 1-reduce task and the map phase of 1-reduce task become slower!**

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem. The more reduce tasks you have, the faster your data gets processed.

The outputs of the map phase are sent to the reducers . If you have two reducers, the load is distributed between the two reducers.

Incase of the wordcount example, you will have two seperate files with count divided between them. So you will have to manually add the total, or run another map reduce job to calculate the total if you had lots of reduce tasks.

Comment: Sorry I think there is some confusion to my description. I have forced that there is no parallelism between reduce tasks because I use only one tasktracker for reduce and I set mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum=1 so there won't be any two reduce task being executed at the same time. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is as expected, if you only have a single reducer than your job has a single point of failure. Your number of reducers should be set to about 90% capacity. You can find your reduce capacity by multiplying your number of reduce slots with your total number of nodes. I have found that it is also good practice to use a combiner if it is applicable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But according to the job log there is no task or node level failure, and I have turned off speculative execution during reduce phase, because I need to figure out the reason that have more waves of reduce task could even be faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just 1 reduce task, then that reducer has to wait for all mappers to finish, and the shuffle phase has to collect all intermediate data to be redirected to just that one reducer. So, it's natural that the map and shuffle times are larger, and so is the overall time, if you have just one reducer.

However if you have more reducers, your data gets processed in parallel, and that makes it faster. Again, if you have too many reducers, then there's too much data being shuffled around, resulting in increase in network traffic. So you have to find that optimal number of reducers which gives you a good balance.

Comment: Sorry I think there is some misunderstanding of "waves" of reduce task. When I say 1 wave of reduce task, there is one reduce task on each tasktracker, and if there are 3 reduce task on each tasktracker, and each tasktracker could process one task at most in one time, this is called 3 waves of reduce task. Here I am only using one tasktracker for reduce and I set the maximum reduce task that could be running on each tasktracker to be one so there shouldn't be any parallelism factors that you discribe. Sorry for the confusing and thanks for your reply anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The right number of reduces seems to be 0.95 or 1.75 * (nodes * mapred.tasktracker.tasks.maximum). At 0.95 all of the reduces can launch immediately and start transfering map outputs as the maps finish. At 1.75 the faster nodes will finish their first round of reduces and launch a second round of reduces doing a much better job of load balancing.

courtesy:

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces

[Setting the number of map tasks and reduce tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885441/setting-the-number-of-map-tasks-and-reduce-tasks)

(similar question wirth resolved answer)

Hope this helps!