# how to force hadoop to use a set number of map tasks

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Running a hadoop job, I set my map to 100 and my reduce to 1 (I am not really reducing anything).

```
conf.setNumMapTasks(100);
conf.setNumReduceTasks(1);
```

After the job runs, I look at the hadoop log I see that one reduce task was used and that zero (0) map task was used. Now I have two questions:

1) Even if my job is very small, shouldn't the number of map task be at least one?

2) Is there a way to force hadoop to run a specified number of map task? I already know that `conf.setNumMapTasks(100)` is just a hint. But is there another way?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this [thread][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885441/setting-the-number-of-map-tasks-and-reduce-tasks

Comment: Actually I read it before posting

Comment: @Ambar: I am particularly interested in the answer to question 1: shouldn't I end up with at least one map (and of course evidence/reference for that). Presently I am getting zero(0) map tasks.