# hadoop: tracking MapReduce tasks

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new to hadoop and this is probably a stupid question but I've been looking for it for hours and cannot find how to do it.

I'm running Hadoop MapReduce with a different number of mappers and reducers to see the difference in performance (e.g. execution time). I want to check if the specified number of mappers/reducers were used but I just can't figure out how I do it.

Hadoop 1.2.1 is installed on a quad-core machine with hyper-threading and I'm sshing to the server, and Hadoop is running in Pseudo-distributed mode.

My MapReduce program was written in Python, so I'm using hadoop-streaming, and this is how I  ran the MR program.

```
$ hadoop jar /Users/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.2.1.jar 
-file /Users/hadoop/map.py 
-mapper /Users/hadoop/map.py 
-file /Users/hadoop/reduce.py 
-reducer /Users/hadoop/reduce.py 
-input file:///Users/hadoop/inputfile 
-output file:///Users/hadoop/outputfile
```

I want to see log information that looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885441/setting-the-number-of-map-tasks-and-reduce-tasks), or anything that provides this kind of information.

Comment: How did you run your python MR program?

Comment: @zsxwing I added how I ran the program in the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a service called the Resource Manager - this web interface includes links to logs like the one you've linked to in your question.  [This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769856/where-is-the-hadoop-task-manager-ui) has some answers about how to reach it.  Given your version of hadoop, from the machine running hadoop you should be able to hit  localhost:50030 to see the Resource Manager.