# where is the hadoop task manager UI

Tags: hadoop

I installed the hadoop 2.2 system on my ubuntu box using this tutorial

http://codesfusion.blogspot.com/2013/11/hadoop-2x-core-hdfs-and-yarn-components.html

Everything worked fine for me and now when I do

```
 http://localhost:50070
```

I can see the management UI for HDFS. Very good!!

But the I am going through another tutorial which tells me that there must be a task manager UI running at http://mymachine.com:50030 and http://mymachine.com:50060

on my machine I cannot open these ports.

I have already done

start-dfs.sh
start-yarn.sh
start-all.sh

is something wrong? why can't I see the task manager UI?

Answer (score 6):

You have installed YARN (MRv2) which runs the ResourceManager. The URL http://mymachine.com:50030 is the web address for the JobTracker daemon that comes with MRv1 and hence you are not able to see it.

To see the ResourceManager UI, check your yarn-site.xml file for the following property:

yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address

By default, it should point to : resource_manager_hostname:8088

Assuming your ResourceManager runs on mymachine, you should see the ResourceManager UI at http://mymachine.com:8088/

Make sure all your deamons are up and running before you visit the URL for the ResourceManager.

Answer (score 1):

For Hadoop 2[aka YARN/MRV2] - Any hadoop installation version-ed 2.x or higher its at port number 8088. eg. localhost:8088

For Hadoop 1 - Any hadoop installation version-ed lower than 2.x[eg 1.x or 0.x] its at port number 50030. eg localhost:50030

Answer (score 1):

By default HadoopUI location is as below
http://mymachine.com:50070