# Hadoop number of Reducers

Tags: hadoop

I am using Hadoop but when I start my job execution mappers are spawned as per number of inputs (which of course is the desired operation) but Hadoop spawns only 1 reducer regardless of input. Although there is a valid input split I don't know why Hadoop spawns only 1 reducer for the task.

Before enforcing more reducers could someone give me a hint as to why this occurs?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885441/setting-the-number-of-map-tasks-and-reduce-tasks

Answer (score 0):

Check if the configuration for the job (either some XML conf file, or something in your driver) contains the property

```
mapred.reduce.tasks=1
```

Some of the example jobs have this configured by default.

Answer (score 0):

By default Hadoop uses only 1 reducer irrespective of the size of the input data. [Here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces) is how to up the number of reducers.