# hadoop:when the file is less than 64M,does increasing the node number have an effect on the processing speed?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I know the default block size is 64M, split is 64M,
then for files less than 64M , when the number of nodes increase from 1 to 6 , there will be only one node to do with the split, so the speed will not improve? Is that right?
If it is a 128M file, there will be 2 nodes to do with the 2 splits, the speed is faster than 1 node, if there are more than 3 nodes, the speed doesn't increase，Is that right?

I don't know if my understanding is correct.Thanks for any comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for your query

> **I know the default block size is 64M,**

In hadoop version 1.0 default size is 64MB and in version 2.0 default size is 128MB. the default block size can be overriden by setting valuue for parameter `dfs.block.size` in the configuration file `hdfs-site.xml`.

> **split is 64M,**

Not necessary, as block size is not same as split size. [Read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549261/split-size-vs-block-size-in-hadoop) for more clarity. For a normal `wordcount` example program, we can safely assume that the split size is *approximately* same as block size.

> **then for files less than 64M , when the number of nodes increase from 1 to 6 , there will be only one node to do with the split, so the speed will not improve? Is that right?**

Yes you are right. If the file size is actually less than block size, then it would be processed by one node, and increasing node from 1 to 6 may not affect the execution speed. However, you must consider the case of speculative execution. In the case of speculative execution, even a smaller file may be processed by 2 nodes simultaneously and hence improve on speed of execution.

From [Yahoo Dev KB link](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html), Speculative execution is explained as below:

> Speculative execution:
>
> One problem with the Hadoop system is that by
>   dividing the tasks across many nodes, it is possible for a few slow
>   nodes to rate-limit the rest of the program. For example if one node
>   has a slow disk controller, then it may be reading its input at only
>   10% the speed of all the other nodes. So when 99 map tasks are already
>   complete, the system is still waiting for the final map task to check
>   in, which takes much longer than all the other nodes.
>
> By forcing tasks to run in isolation from one another, individual
>   tasks do not know where their inputs come from. Tasks trust the Hadoop
>   platform to just deliver the appropriate input. Therefore, the same
>   input can be processed multiple times in parallel, to exploit
>   differences in machine capabilities. As most of the tasks in a job are
>   coming to a close, the Hadoop platform will schedule redundant copies
>   of the remaining tasks across several nodes which do not have other
>   work to perform. This process is known as speculative execution. When
>   tasks complete, they announce this fact to the JobTracker. Whichever
>   copy of a task finishes first becomes the definitive copy. If other
>   copies were executing speculatively, Hadoop tells the TaskTrackers to
>   abandon the tasks and discard their outputs. The Reducers then receive
>   their inputs from whichever Mapper completed successfully, first.
>
> *Speculative execution is enabled by default*. You can disable
>   speculative execution for the mappers and reducers by setting the
>   `mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution` and
>   `mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution` `JobConf` options to false,
>   respectively using old API, while with newer API you may consider changing `mapreduce.map.speculative` and `mapreduce.reduce.speculative`.

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming a large file is splittable to begin with, which isn't always the case.

If your files are ever less than a block size, adding more nodes will never increase processing time, it'll only help with replication and total cluster capacity.

Otherwise, your understanding seems correct, though, I think the latest default is actually 128 MB, not 64