# Spark RDD vs Dataframe - Data storage

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I am new to Spark & learning about the Dataframe,operations & architecture. While reading about the comparison between RDD and Dataframe, i got confused with the data structure of both RDD and Dataframe. Below are my observation, Please help to clarify/correct it if it is wrong

1)RDD is stored in the computer RAM in a distributed manner(blocks) across the nodes in a cluster,if the source data is an a cluster(eg: HDFS).

If the data source is just a single CSV file, the data will be distributed to multiple blocks in the RAM of running server(if Laptop). Am i right?

2)Is there any relationship between block and partition? Which one is super set?

3)Dataframe: Does the Dataframe also getting stored in the same way as RDD? Whether RDD will be created in the backed if i am storing my source data into dataframe alone?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You could find lot of reading material online for Spark. Even Apache Spark documentation is quit detailed. In addition to that you could also refer https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> RDD is stored in the computer RAM in a distributed manner(blocks) across the nodes in a cluster, if the source data is an a cluster(eg: HDFS).

If `caching` or `checkpointing` is enabled it is also might be stored either in memory or on disk. Also, shuffling always involves disk write.

> If the data source is just a single CSV file, the data will be distributed to multiple blocks in the RAM of running server(if Laptop). Am i right?

CSV file will be split into multiple partitions, and each task will only read a chunk of data (start-end offsets).

> Is there any relationship between block and partition? Which one is super set?

It is a bit confusing, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549261/split-size-vs-block-size-in-hadoop) which states that `split` is a logical division of the input data while a `block` is a physical division of data.
Spark uses its own terminology and `partition` in Spark has roughly the same meaning as split in Hadoop.

When a file is read from HDFS [HadoopRDD](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/HadoopRDD.scala#L212) is being used and under the hood, each `split` will become a `partition`.

> Dataframe: Does the Dataframe also getting stored in the same way as RDD? Whether RDD will be created in the backed if i am storing my source data into dataframe alone?

Dataframe is nothing else than RDD[InternalRow] under the hood.
Take a look at the [SparkPlan](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkPlan.scala#L127).

Comment: Thanks!!.so, there is no concept like block in spark? It is only in HDFS(128MB)?