# How to print the result from reducer into single file

Tags: python, hadoop, amazon-web-services, emr

I am using Amazon EMR and because of the way it works (parallel) my output gets split in multiple files.

But i would like to have one file instead with the right sequence, is it possible to do just that?

my last lines in reducer are like this

```
for key, value in doc_dict.iteritems():
    print key
    for k, v in value.iteritems():
        print k,v
```

this is driving me crazy, i cant present results as they are mixed up.

Comment: what is the shell command you're running to submit the job. are you using `hadoop-streaming`?

Comment: @maxymoo   i am using the ruby aws sdk, and yes its hadoop-streaming

Comment: You could probably limit the number of reducers (eg set) to 1 using `mapreduce.job.reduces`. See also: [Setting the number of map tasks and reduce tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885441/setting-the-number-of-map-tasks-and-reduce-tasks)

Answer (score 1):

You have to run a script to merge the part files

```
hadoop fs -getmerge /output/dir/on/hdfs/ /desired/local/output/file.txt
```

or you could write them to an external database within your reducers, and then rip your result out of that.
For one project I did I found that HBase was very useful for this

Comment: i should propably say that i am writing in an S3 bucket, does this work the same?

Comment: hmmm... don't know about that, doubt it. I assumed you were writing to HDFS native.

Comment: petros don't write to an s3 bucket, write to the hdfs, then you can upload after doing the getmerge

Comment: hmm the thing is i need to run that command using either the GUI for now and then later the AWS SDK. i assume that command is executed using the aws CLI ?

Comment: surely the ruby aws sdk has a way to upload to s3, that's one of core features of aws

Comment: my workflow is like this, i deploy from a ruby app, an EMR cluster and add step, that step gets executeed and results saved to s3 bucket directly. I do not know how to configure HDFS native through the sdk.