# Controlling number of map and reduce jobs spawned?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am trying to understand how may map reduce jobs get started for a task and how to control the number of MR jobs.

Say I have a 1TB file in HDFS and my block size is 128MB. 
For a MR task on this 1TB file if I specify the input split size as 256MB then how many Map and Reduce jobs gets started. From my understanding this is dependent on split size. i.e number of Map jobs = total size of file / split size and in this case it works out to be `1024 * 1024 MB / 256 MB = 4096`. So the number of map task started by hadoop is 4096.
**1) Am I right?**

2) If I think that this is an inappropriate number, can I inform hadoop to start less number of jobs or even more number of jobs. **If yes how?**

And how about the number of reducer jobs spawned, I think this is totally controlled by the user.
**3) But how and where should I mention the number of reducer jobs required.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the number of map tasks and reduce tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885441/setting-the-number-of-map-tasks-and-reduce-tasks)

Answer (score 2):

**1. Yes, you're right. No of mappers=(size of data)/(input split size). So, in your case it would be 4096**

2. As per my understanding ,Before hadoop-2.7 you can only hint system to create number of mapper by `conf.setNumMapTasks(int num)` but mapper will created by their own. From hadoop-2.7 you can limit number of mapper by `mapreduce.job.running.map.limit`. See this [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5583) ticket
3. By default number of reducer is 1. You can change it by **job.setNumReduceTasks(integer_numer);**

You can also provide this parameter from cli 
`-Dmapred.reduce.tasks=<num reduce tasks>`