# Is there a way to specify the number of mappers in Scalding?

Tags: mapreduce, scalding

I am new to scalding world. My scalding job will have multiple stages, and I need to tune each stage individually.

I have found that we might be able to change the number of reducers by using `withReducers`. Also, I am able to set the split size for the input data by the job config. However, I didn't see there is any way to change the number of mappers for my sub-tasks on the fly.

Did I miss something? Does anyone know how to specify the number of mappers for my sub-tasks? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got some answers/ideas might be helpful for someone else who shared the same question.

> It is much easier to control reducers compared to mappers.
>
> Mappers are controlled by hadoop without a similar simple knob. You can set some config parameters to give hadoop an idea of how many map tasks to launch.
>
> This stack overflow may be helpful:
> [Setting the number of map tasks and reduce tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885441/setting-the-number-of-map-tasks-and-reduce-tasks)

One workaround I could think of is changing your major task to small ones, which you could individually tweak the size (# of mappers) of your input data.